# Polymorphic associations with has_one doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these model classes:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :urls, as: :media
  has_one :url, as: :media
end

class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true
end
```

The strange thing here is that `Song.first.url` always returns nil, but `Song.first.urls` returns a list of urls.

Here is the generated SQL queries:

```
Song.includes(:url).first.url # => nil

Song Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` LIMIT 1
Url Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `urls`.* FROM `urls` WHERE `urls`.`media_type` = 'Song' AND `urls`.`media_id` IN (1)

Song.includes(:urls).first.urls # => [list of urls]

Song Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `songs`.* FROM `songs` LIMIT 1
Url Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `urls`.* FROM `urls` WHERE `urls`.`media_type` = 'Song' AND `urls`.`media_id` IN (1)
```

I'm running rails 3.2.0.rc2 on Ruby 1.9.2

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I wonder if it's a bug...

Comment: What if you remove `has_many` from the model? What if you do `Song.includes(:url, :urls).first.url`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Removing the `has_many` relations results in the same thing.

Comment: Have you trie putting a condition clause to qualify the has_one relationship?  How is the one linked picked?  Is it the first url in the associated table with this song_id?  If so, try putting that in condition of the association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault, I had accidently implemented my own `Song#url` method. It took me a while to find it.